# Rudin $1.29$ theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

There are the theorems which we need for the proof of this theorem:
[image]
[image]
There is the theorem $1.29$ :

Suppose  $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ is  measurable, and

$\phi(E) = \int_E f \,d\mu$   ( $E$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M $ ( it's $\sigma$-algebra)

Then $\phi$ is a measure on $\mathfrak M$, and

$\int_X g  d\phi$ $=$  $\int_X gf \,d\mu$

for every measurable $g$ on $X$ with range in $[0, \infty]$.

There is the proof:

Let $E_1, E_2, E_3,...$ be disjoint members of $\mathfrak M$ whose union is $E$.

observe that $\chi_E$$f$ $=$ $\sum_{j=1}^\infty$ $\chi_{E_j}$$f$

and that

$\phi(E)$ $=$ $\int_X$ $\chi_E$$f$ $d\mu$
$\phi(E_j)$ $=$ $\int_X$ $\chi_{E_j}$$f$ $d\mu$

It now follows from theorem $1.27$ that

$\phi(E)$ $=$ $\sum_{j=1}^\infty$ $\phi(E_j)$

Since $\phi(\emptyset)$ $=$ $0$, the last equality proofs that $\phi$ is a measure.

Next, $\phi(E) = \int_E f \,d\mu$   ( $E$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M $ ( it's $\sigma$-algebra) shows that $\int_X g  d\phi$ $=$  $\int_X gf \,d\mu$ holds whenever $g$ $=$ $\chi_E$ for some $E$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M$. Hence $\int_X g  d\phi$ $=$  $\int_X gf \,d\mu$ holds for every simple measurable function g, and the general case follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

I don't understand how does the general case follows from the monotone convergence theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assume that $g \ge 0$. Choose a sequence of simple measurable functions $\{g_n\}$ such that $g_n \nearrow g$. Then since $f \ge 0$, also $g_n f \nearrow gf$ so that
$$\int_X g d\phi = \lim_n \int_X g_n d\phi = \lim_n \int_X g_nf d \mu = \int_X gf d\mu.$$
Here the first and last equality follow from two applications of the monotone convergence theorem, while the middle equality follows because you know the result for simple functions.

If $g$ is real-valued, write it as $g= g^+ - g^-$ with $g^+, g^- \ge 0$ to deduce the result in general.